# How to change the location of the TOC in a MediaWiki skin

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I'm woking on a MediaWiki skin for my site. For the page content I'm using `<?= $this->html( 'bodycontent' ); ?>` to output it all. Part of this, on longer pages, is the Table of Contents (TOC).

I would like to move the location of the TOC out of the body an into the sidebar but I'm not sure how to prevent the TOC from showing in the `bodycontent` or where to get the raw data to display it in the sidebar.

I'm hoping there is a data time similar to `$this->data['sidebar']['navigation']` that I can use to format it how I want.

How can I turn off the TOC in the `bodycontent`?

Is there a `$this->data` location that has the TOC data?

Answer (score 2):

The MediaWiki skinning system is not really designed for this, but someone created an extension to make your work easier: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:DeToc

Using that extension you would do something like this (inside `function execute()`):

```
$body = $this->data['bodycontent'];
$new_body = DeToc::RemoveToc($body, $extracted_toc);

/* Print body */
echo $new_body;

/* Print TOC somewhere else */
echo $extracted_toc;
```

Alternatively you could just turn off the TOC, using `$parser->mShowToc = false;`, and then create the TOC yourself. MediaWiki internally uses a regex like this to find all sections: `'/^\={2,5}(.*?)\={2,5}$/m'`